# MySQL User Profile System

Tags: mysql, profile

Does MySQL have a user profile system where I can associate "permissions" and "rights" etc. with a certain user profile and assign each user to a certain profile ? For example, I want to create the profile "Intern" for student interns, "Programmers" for programmers in the organizations, "ReadOnly" for people in the organization who only need to be able to read data.

If MySQL does not nativaly provide such a system, what is a good desktop software for Linux or for Windows that allows me to do this kind of management ?

Cheers !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there's no way to do that, eventually you could play with the mysql.user table to copy permission of an user to another using SQL statements.